# Laravel Exceptions Handler not work

Tags: php, laravel, exception, laravel-5.1

Environment: Laravel 5.1, PHP 5.6.10

I tried to implement `App\Exceptions\Handler::render()` to response error message in JSON format.

The `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` as follows:

```
// ignore..

public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    } elseif ($e instanceof AbstractException) {
        return response()->apiJsonError(
                $e->getMessage(),
                $e->getErrors(),
                $e->statusCode());
    }

    // ignore...
}
```

In controller, it also throws an exception:

```
if (ArrayUtil::isIndexExceed($list, $maxIndex)) {
    // Index exceeds
    throw new App\Exceptions\ExceedingIndexException;
}
```

However, when the error occurs, the Handler::render() is not invoked. The response is the `ExceedingIndexException` stack.

**The following part is Exception class**

My custom exception class, `ExceedingIndexException`:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

use App\Http\Responses\Error;
use App\Exceptions\AbstractException;

class ExceedingIndexException extends AbstractException
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $message = 'Unable to execute';
        $error = new Error('exceeding_index_value');
        $statusCode = 400;

        parent::__construct($statusCode, $error, $message);
    }
}
```

The `ExceedingIndexException` class inherits `AbstractException`:

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

abstract class AbstractException extends \Exception
{
    protected $statusCode;
    protected $errors;

    public function __construct(
        $statusCode, $errors, $message, $code = 0, \Exception $previous = null) {
        parent::__construct($message, $code, $previous);

        $this->statusCode = $statusCode;
        $this->errors = $errors;
    }

    public function getStatusCode() 
    {
        return $this->statusCode;
    }

    public function getErrors() 
    {
        return $this->errors;
    }
}
```

**Solution**

I found my project depends on Dingo API for RESTful API. Because, Dingo also supports and registers its own exception handler, `App\Exceptions\Handler` doesn't be invoked.

I tried to use [Custom Exception Responses in Dingo API](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses#custom-exception-responses) as my Exception Handler to response error in JSON format. And it works for me.

Comment: I think the issue has nothing to do with your `ExceedingIndexException` which is located inside the controller. Apart from `ModelNotFoundException` what error should occur before `AbstractException` is triggered ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can replace the Dingo API error handler by a custom error handler. Get a copy of https://github.com/KIVagant/api/blob/develop/src/Exception/Handler.php
and save it to YourApp\Exceptions\Api\V1\Handler.php. Add interface Dingo\Api\Contract\Debug\ExceptionHandler to it, 
then follow the instruction in [Exceptions now can return any additional data](https://github.com/dingo/api/pull/420).

```
use Dingo\Api\Contract\Debug\ExceptionHandler as DingoExceptionHandler;
class Handler implements ExceptionHandler, DingoExceptionHandler {
```

Replace the error handler, eg in boot ().

```
// Resolve YourApp\Exceptions\Api\V1\Handler ifself
$this->app->alias('api.exception', 'YourApp\Exceptions\Api\V1\Handler');

$this->app->singleton('api.exception', function ($app) {
    return new \YourApp\Exceptions\Api\V1\Handler($app['Illuminate\Contracts\Debug\ExceptionHandler'],
            $app['config']['api.errorFormat'], $app['config']['api.debug']);
});
```

Don't forget set error format. You can set up error format in boot(), eg:

```
// Set up error format
$this->app['api.exception']->setErrorFormat(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, Dingo API took over the Exception handling.

You you face similar problems where Lumen Exception handler isn't handling anything, probably some package took over the handling. In this case it was Dingo API.

Register your custom response for the exception for Dingo API:
https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Errors-And-Error-Responses#custom-exception-responses

Comment: Please include the important bits from your link in your post